# Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R},c\in(a,b),$ and $f'(c)>0.$ Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>f(c)$ if $c<x<c+\delta.$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

This question was on a practice final exam for my Elementary Real Analysis course. It says:

> Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R},c\in(a,b),$ and $f'(c)>0.$ Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>f(c)$ if $c<x<c+\delta.$

My solution was slightly different than their solution, so I'm wondering if this solution is correct? Here is my attempt:

**Proof:** Since $f'(c)$ exists, $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ such that if $x\in(a,b)$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta,$ then

$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|<\epsilon. $$

Now choose $\epsilon=\frac{f'(c)}{2}.$ Then there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $c<x<c+\delta,$ then

$\begin{gather} \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right|<\frac{f'(c)}{2}\\
-\frac{f'(c)}{2}<\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)<\frac{f'(c)}{2}\\
\frac{f'(c)}{2}<\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}<\frac{3f'(c)}{2}\\
0<\frac{f'(c)}{2}(x-c)<f(x)-f(c)<\frac{3f'(c)}{2}(x-c),
\end{gather}$

So then $f(x)>f(c).\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks fine to me.